# Get cell from row

Tags: vba, excel, row, cell

I'm writing code in VBA, and I'm trying to accomplish the following :

- Select a range from a sheet
- Loop through that range's rows
- Compare the 3 cell value in the row to a value
- Do stuff....

I searched through the Internet, but didn't find a way to access that 3rd cell...

Thanks in advance !

Some code for you nerds :

```
For Each ProdRow In DayProd.Rows
  saisi = False
  Do While ((Not IsEmpty(Selection.Value)) And (Not saisi))
    If (Selection.Value = ProdRow(*Select that 3rd cell*).Value) Then
        ....                  
    End If
  Loop
Next
```

Comment: You would benefit greatly from reading this: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  You are also looking for the [Range.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) property.  Hard to give more tips without more information.

Comment: `If Selection.Value = ProdRow.Offset(0, 3).Cells(1, 1).Value Then`

Comment: I'm not using Select, I'm seeking just the way to refer to a cell : each row containes three cells (That is 3 columns), how to get that done ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) function like @ omegasripes mentioned

Or the [Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx) function:

```
Cells(ProdRow.Row, ProdRow.Column+3)
```

Or if you want the third column ("C") of that row just:

```
Cells(ProdRow.Row, 3)
```

Comment: The ProdRow adress is $C$4:$E$4, isn't there a way to refer to those cells Inside the row range ?

Comment: yes, if this is your address, then you could refer to the third column like this: `ProdRow.Columns(3).Value`